# Switch Visual Studio 2010 License keys

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have used one license key and want to switch my configuration to use another key.

I tried to launched the uninstall wizard from "Add/Remove Programs" in the Windows Control Panel. When I reinstalled, the license still work.

How can I modify my Visual Studio 2010 installation to use another key, and possibly without uninstalling and reinstalling?

**Sorry for not clarifying it at the beginning. Actually, a valid key is not available to me for now. Is there a way to remove the original license completely and use VS as a trial version for days.**

Comment: Not the sort of thing I'd admit to on a public forum.

Comment: Are you intending to use another license key? **Your question didn't actually state that.**

Comment: @p.campbell Yes, of course. I am intending to use it legally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the serial number after Visual Studio 2010 installation

1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features, locate and highlight Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate/Premium/Professional installation, and click on Uninstall/Change button.
2. Upgrade Visual Studio 2010 Product Key for Activation
3. A Visual Studio setup maintenance screen should be shown. After clicking Next button, an option to enter a valid serial number to upgrade product license is available.
4. Enter the upgrade key accordingly, and click on Activate button. No re-installation required.

Comment: Unfortunately this options does not come up when VS2010 was installed through MSDN download... no option for updating product key in Uninstall/Change

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to edit the product key in a file called `Setup.SDB`. It should be located in

`\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU\Setup.SDB`

Edit this file in a notepad and search for `Product key`. You can then update the product key.

I actually repaired the installation after this change just to make sure everything was working. This was tested on `VS2008` and `VS2010`